# Is there a way to save tramp targets and then incrementally filter them with Helm?

Tags: helm, tramp

Say I want to open new connections to `superlongusername1@superlongdomain1.org`, `superlongusername2@superlongdomain2.org` and `superlongusername3@superlongdomain3.org` frequently, but I don't want to type each one every time. It would be nice if the target was saved the on the first successful connection and then presented to me as an option for ever connection thereafter which then could be incrementally filtered with Helm.

By analogy, it would be very similar to `helm-recentf` but instead of the file names they would be tramp targets.

Comment: Uh, Tramp targets ***are*** file (or directory) names. `recentf` works fine with remote files - have you tried it? And you can bookmark remote files...

Comment: The Tramp manual discusses several approaches to shorten longish file names, see `(info "(tramp) Frequently Asked Questions")`. I don't know whether they cooperate with helm, 'tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`helm-tramp`](https://github.com/masasam/emacs-helm-tramp) might be what you are looking for. It reads the connections in `~/.ssh/config` and pushes them to the `helm` interface. I haven't tried `helm-tramp` yet myself, though.

Answer (score 2):

I use tramp in conjunction with bookmarks, so you avoid having to type in long names repeatedly. And there is a command helm-bookmarks, which lets you choose among your bookmarks.